# how to disabled each items in gridview according to the textbox text?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image]

if booking closed column values is equal or more than textbox1 text then the book button in gridview will be disabled for each gridview item whose booking closed time is greater and equal to textbox1 time ..

How to do that ?

M using VS 2008 and vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this issue in the rowbound event handler of the GridView.

Update #1

```
protected void books_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
            if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {

                //Do this only if the textbox value is ....
                Button btn =  (( GridView )sender).FindControl("button");
                btn.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Update #2

```
Protected Sub books_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

  'Do this only if the textbox value is ....
  Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, GridView).FindControl("button")
  btn.Enabled = False
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can u please guide me with som eof the coding ...

HOw would i perform this in VB.NET?

Comment: Can you create event handlers?

Comment: No, i dint understand how to do thta..can you provide me the cding for that ?

Comment: You have to go to the HTML view of you page then the properties pane. 
Double click on the bolt sign and look for the RowDataBound event. You'll have an empty SUB similar to the one above. Just fill in the remaining code.

Comment: Sir...how to disabled button of those row whose cell text is equal to textbox text ?

Comment: It gives the error message when i try to run ...

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Create the event handler first and update your question, so i could see what you have.

Comment: My simple question is // if i have two column in grid view namely name and age and button Status 

i want when textbox1.text = Gridview name column then the button corresponding to that row would be disabed ..

Comment: You have to replace the "button" with the name of the button in the gridview.

Comment: I want when textbox text is equal to the text displayed in name cell of gridview then that gridview row button will be disabled

Comment: You should be able to do e.row.findControl instead of DirectCast(sender, GridView)